# PHP Implode - variable between text

Tags: php, function, implode

I have this:

```
<?php echo implode("<th></th>", $days); ?>
```

Although, that outputs:

```
Today<th></th>02-03<th></th>01-03<th></th>29-02<th></th>28-02<th></th>27-02<th></th>26-02
```

As you can see, the `<th> and </th>` is not formatted correct, as I want to have the date ($days) variable in between them like this `<th>Today</th><th>02-03</th`> and so on...

How can I obtain this?

Comment: it is formatted correct. if you want to add some tags to the resulting string, you may add them.

Comment: `implode` works correctly, just not the way you want it to ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flip the order of your separator, then add the surrounding tags.

```
<?php echo "<th>" . implode("</th><th>", $days) . "</th>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  <?php  foreach( $days as $day ) 
        echo "<th>$day</th>";
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo "<th>" . implode("</th><th>", $days) ."</th>"; ?>
```